# What event is triggered when a e-mail is opened in preview pane?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using code like this to catch the open event from an e-mail, but this only fires when you actually double click on an e-mail. Is there a way to also run the code when the e-mail is opened in the preview pane?

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Public EventsDisable As Boolean

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    EventsDisable = True
    'do something
    EventsDisable = False
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the Explorer.SelectionChange event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/explorer-selectionchange-event-outlook.